# Pn532 doesnt detect sometimes

Tags: esp32, esp

Im using ESP32 with PN532 NFC module with I2C
And Im using this library https://github.com/elechouse/PN532
And using this documents https://www.elechouse.com/elechouse/images/product/PN532_module_V3/PN532_%20Manual_V3.pdf

Normally, it finds the PN532 and reads the card successfully when I scan it. However, sometimes after starting, it doesn't detect the PN532 and never finds it.It say PN53x card not found!. When I unplug and plug in the sensor cable, the ESP32 can detect the sensor, but I shouldn't have to do it this way. Therefore, if it can't find the PN532 twice, I wanted to reset it as follows:

```
void resetPN532() {
digitalWrite(PNP532_IRQ_Pin, LOW);
delay(100);
digitalWrite(PNP532_IRQ_Pin, HIGH);
delay(100);
digitalWrite(PNP532_RSTO_Pin, LOW);
delay(100);
digitalWrite(PNP532_RSTO_Pin, HIGH);
 }
```

This is code for the find:

```
`  uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
  
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
  processCommand("command");
  }

  if (!versiondata) {
    Serial.println("PN53x card not found!");
    resetCounter++;
    if (resetCounter >= 2) {
      Serial.println("Reset PNP");
      resetPN532();
      resetCounter = 0;
    }


    return false;
  }

`
```

This is my connections:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXwmk.png)

Why I faced with this issue I dont know but how can I solve this problem ?

. When I unplug and plug in the sensor cable, the ESP32 can detect the sensor, but I shouldn't have to do it this way. Therefore, if it can't find the PN532 twice, I wanted to reset it as follows:

Comment: the code does not compile without error

Comment: I share the part of the code. Not all of them

Comment: @jsotola what you mean?

Comment: " PN53x card not found" basically means it can't establish a communication with PN53x. You need to check your wiring, your power supply, your noise, and your code. to find out the root cause. If the sensor can't be found, how can you be sure that you can reset it via software? You got one problem in establishing a communication, instead of finding the root cause, now you got two problems.